# How to use Yard to document enumerable type and the types that they contain?

Tags: ruby, enumerable, yard

Using the ruby Yard doc tool I can write

```
# @param bar [String]
def foo(bar)
end
```

however if the parameter is an enumerable

```
# @param bar [Enumerable[String]]
def foo(bar)
end
```

Is the above the correct way or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
# @param [Enumerable<String>] bar
def foo(bar)
end
```

Reference: http://rubydoc.info/docs/yard/file/docs/GettingStarted.md#Declaring_Types